# Android: parsing json with 'null' values using Gson

Tags: android, json, gson

I got the following request from an **Android developer**:

> Would you change the webservice back-end so that it **returnes empty
>   strings** for empty fields **instead of null**.

The Android json **parser converts null to** a string containing **"null"**.

The code:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
//...
private OrganizationSearchResult result;
//...
Gson gson = new Gson();
result = gson.fromJson(resultString, OrganizationSearchResult.class);
```

Is this a known issue?

If so, is there a known work-around for it?

Comment: post your code and if have logcat ,post also it

Comment: I believe your Android developer is mistaken. Android's JSON APIs allow you to detect null and cope with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know what you are using for parsing the json and the JSONObject class in android sdk doesnt do that.

Take a look at the following class

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

Check out `has` and `isNULL` of the above method.

I think GSON automatically handles the null in json by converting them to java null.

Answer (score 0):

there will be a method isNull(key) in jsonObject to Determine if the value associated with the key is null or if there is no value, check with this and then call `getString(key)`.